# Gini coefficient with keras in python

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, gini

I want to calculate simple NN model with gini coefficient as its optimizer function. Here is the my gini function:

```
def gini(actual, pred):
    nT = K.shape(actual)[-1]
    n = K.cast(nT, dtype='int32')
    inds = K.reverse(tf.nn.top_k(pred, n)[1], axes=[0])
    a_s = K.gather(actual, inds)
    a_c = K.cumsum(a_s)
    n = K.cast(nT, dtype=K.floatx())
    giniSum = K.cast(K.sum(a_c) / K.sum(a_s), dtype=K.floatx()) - (n + 1) / 2.0

    return giniSum / n


def gini_normalized(a, p):
    return gini(a, p) / gini(a, a)
```

And this is how I compile my model:

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(60,)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss=gini_normalized, optimizer=sgd)

    return model
```

I always get this error "ValueError: None values not supported.", can anyone tell me what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This error is typical for functions that are not differentiable. (It also happens when some var is `None` and shouldn't be. Sometimes it's the case that someone forgot to add the `return` statement to a custom function somewhere or something like that).

In your case, it's not differentiable, indeed.

All the final values are coming only from `actual`, and `actual` is constant. (Your model can't be trained with such a function)

The var `pred` is the one that is connected to the model's weights, but the only part that `pred` is taking in the function is sorting the values in `actual`. But sorting is not a differentiable action.

There is probably nothing you can do about it, since your Gini function should indeed take values from `actual` as you did.